# How to pre-fill a form with Django?

Tags: python, django, django-crispy-forms

I have a Django app with instances of restaurants. I want my users to be able to update restaurants. However, when a user gets to the update_restaurant.html form, i want the form to be pre-populated so that if the user only wants to edit one field, he doesn't need to re-fill all the other fields. I'm using crispy forms.

restaurant_update.html:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load static %}
{% block page_content %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}



<div class="container">

  <h1> Update {{ restaurant.name|title }}
  </h1>
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  {% csrf_token %}
  {{ form|crispy }}
  <input type="submit" value="Update Restaurant" class="btn btn-primary"/>
</form>



</div>

{% endblock %}
```

forms.py:

```
from django import forms
from .models import Restaurant, Comment


class RestaurantForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Restaurant
        fields = ['name', 'description', 'address', 'image']
```

models.py:

```
class Restaurant(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=1000)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    image = CloudinaryField('image', null=True, blank=True)
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE,  default=1)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

views.py:

```
def restaurant_update(request, pk):
    restaurant = get_object_or_404(Restaurant, pk=pk)

    if not restaurant.user_can_delete(request.user):
        return redirect('restaurant_detail', pk=pk)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = RestaurantForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=restaurant)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('restaurant_detail', pk=pk)
    else:
        form = RestaurantForm(instance=restaurant)

    context = {
        'restaurant': restaurant,
        'form': form
    }
    return render(request, 'restaurant_update.html', context)
```

I tried using Initial in my view but it doesnt work. I still see an empty form whenever i go to restaurant_update view url.

Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: To me your code looks legit. You basically do the same as described [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/forms/modelforms/#providing-initial-values). Try to temporarily remove the crispy tag to check if that tag could be the reason. Also: You don't have to go to restaurant_update.html, you specifically have to go to that `restaurant_update`-view's url.

Comment: Puzzling. I have views like yours which work the way you expect: to display the current object fields so you can optionally update them. The main difference is that I use CBV `UpdateView`, not FBV.

Answer (score 1):

OK so I've found a way to work around this issue. I post it here in case someone faces the same issue.

```
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  {% csrf_token %}
  <div class="form-group">
    {{ form.name.label }}
    <input type="text"
           class="form-control"
           name="name"
           value="{{ restaurant.name }}">
    {{ form.description.label }}
    <input type="text"
           class="form-control"
           name="description"
           value="{{ restaurant.description }}">
    {{ form.address.label }}
    <input type="text"
           class="form-control"
           name="address"
           value="{{ restaurant.address }}">
    {{ form.image.label }}
    <div class="custom-file">
      <input type="file"
             class="custom-file-input"
             name="image"
             value="{{ restaurant.image }}">
      <label class="custom-file-label" for="{{ form.image.label }}">restaurant's image</label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<input type="submit" value="Update Restaurant" class="btn btn-primary" />
```

The idea behind this is to pass the values in the form template directly. I know this is not best practices but it works. (It works with plain Django forms too)

Comment: You could also remove the if-else logic and address the fields directly via: `{{ form.description.id_for_label }}`, `{{ form.description.label }}`, ... and finally `{{ form.image.name }}`

Answer (score 1):

You should consider [UpdateView](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#updateview).

```
class ResturantUpdateView(UpdateView):
  model = Restaurant
  form_class = RestaurantForm
```

urls:

```
path('update-restaurant/<int:pk>/', ResturantUpdateView.as_view(), name='update-restaurant')
```

where pk is the primary key of the Restaurant object you want to update.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, but give this a try:

```html
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load static %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}  <!--Changed order!-->

{% block page_content %}
<!-- Leave everything as is -->
{% endblock %}
```

You might not be able to load that crispy tag from within the block with the content. Give it a shot, might be wrong.

Comment: It doesn't work unfortunately: the forms still aren't pre-populated